# My tweets are not showing up in other people's mentions

Tags: twitter

My replies are not showing up in other people's mentions. I tried tweeting several friends, my other accounts but my tweets just won't appear in their mentions? They do appear on my own Twitter page. It's been almost 24 hours now and it's pretty frustrating.

Comment: Is your account private? If yes, are the users you tweeted following you?

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 5):

From the [Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/370610):

> If you're having trouble with @replies or mentions, check for the following:
>
> - **Is there a symbol in/after the username?** If you write **@Support.123**, your message will be sent to the user **@Support**, not **@Support123**.
> - **Is there text or a symbol preceding the @ symbol?**  If you write **.@Support** or **?@Support**, it will appear as a regular Tweet, meaning all of your followers will see it in their timeline, rather than just you, the intended recipient and those who follow both of you.
> - **Is there a letter preceding the @ symbol?** If you write **123@Support** or **word@Support**, Support will not receive your Tweet. Mentions and @replies will not work with letters or numbers in front of the @ symbol. The @ symbol must be at the beginning of a Tweet or it must have a space directly in front of it in order for the mention to work.
> - **Are your Tweets protected?** If your Tweets are protected, the person you're trying to @reply or mention has to be one of your approved followers in order to see your Tweet. For example, if @Support has protected Tweets, @justinbieber won't be able to see their Tweets unless he follows that account.
> - **Are you looking for your @replies?** If you’re not seeing your @reply listed below a user’s original Tweet, it’s because we are currently unable to show every reply to a given Tweet in that Tweet’s details. Rest assured that if your @reply is showing up in your timeline, the other user can see your @reply in their Mentions tab.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your account may be marked for spam.

Comment: I disagree with Andrew, but I think that the post doesn't include enough details. Please explain how the OP could know if her account was marked for spam.

Comment: This is doubtlessly the case. The "we can't show every tweet publicly" and then removing tweets of users who have been blocked by someone for example is likely part of the algorithm.